# Elastic Wild card search not working with space

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to make search from elastic search index, using wildcard filter, it working properly till i use "space" in my search criteria.

Ex : if value in elastic index is "This is test value"

when i use search value : "This*" --> Working, fetching the value
when i use search value : "This is*"--> not working, resulting in zero match

my code looks as follows

QueryBuilders.**wildcardQuery**(
ElasticSearchUtil.FIELDNAME, searchValue.toLowerCase())

how can i handle space and make my search successful?

regards
UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wildcard query works only with a single token. What you are trying to do is to find one token followed by another token with the second token being specified by a prefix. This can be achieved by using [match phrase prefix](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#_match_phrase_prefix) query. Your query would look like this:

QueryBuilders.matchPhrasePrefixQuery(ElasticSearchUtil.FIELDNAME, searchValue)

Please note that the `searchValue` shouldn't have "*" at the end.